# Rails: Finding the record that the current object belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: ModelA and ModelB

ModelB has many ModelA

My questions:

1) Is it necessary to have a belongs to association in ModelA?
   (If this is necessary, please let me know and assume that it has been included in the next question. I tried both ways)

2) I have a record from ModelA and i want to find ModelB. How would i do it?
I know that if i wanted to do it the other way around it will be:
    @modelb.modelas.all
    should i use:
    @modela.modelb 
work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_b
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_as
end
```

1. Yes you need to set up a `belongs_to` association.
2. Just use `model_a.model_b`. Everything should work fine if the model A has the `model_b_id` attribute set to some existing ID value. You can check whether the ID is set using `Rails.logger.debug model_a.inspect`.